# Meaning of "delay off/on"

Tags: meaning, differences

I am looking at the controlling system of an commercial ironing system. One of the terms used is "Delay off/On", I'm not sure what it means. Is it "the delay is off/on" or "the off/on is delayed"? Thanks

Comment: As they say in other forums -- RTFM.  You would have to read the manual to know, if there are no "contextual" clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not part of ordinary English, and in the abstract its meaning cannot be reliably determined.

But *in context* buttons and controls which bear a legend including "on/off" are usually intended to switch the named feature on and off.